# Cassandra : How to send multiple write/read requests in a single client request?

Tags: java, cassandra, pipeline

I am working on an application, where I need to send multiple requests to the cassandra server. The individual requests are kind of a write/read requests, with short interval of execution. I am observing a major bottleneck in round trip time.

Can I pipeline the requests to the cassandra to avoid RTT, just like pipelining in Redis.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Cassandra 1.2 or greater, you can use `BATCH` to wrap up multiple `INSERT` / `UPDATE` statements.

For example:

```
BEGIN BATCH
  INSERT INTO users (userid, password, name)
      VALUES ('user2', 'ch@ngem3b', 'second user');
  UPDATE users SET password = 'ps22dhds' WHERE userid = 'user3';
  INSERT INTO users (userid, password) VALUES ('user4', 'ch@ngem3c');
  DELETE name FROM users WHERE userid = 'user1';
APPLY BATCH;
```

[See CQL3 Batch documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#batchStmt).

Comment: Can we somehow do the similar things for read, just like a multi-get feature. I understand, batch cannot be done for the reads. I can use a SELECT IN however, but I cannot use variable bound variables dynamically I suppose.